# Google App Engine - JBoss authentication

Tags: web-services, security, google-app-engine, jboss

I have a web service hosted in a JBoss AS. Add a app running on Google App Engine. Now I want to access my web service hosted in JBoss AS only by my App Engine app and I want to restrict others from accessing my web service. How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [AppEngine URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) to call your JBoss web services from your AppEngine app.  Use the HTTPS option to secure the network connection.  Furthermore create request headers and payload such as to satisfy whatever JBoss security requirements you can establish between JBoss and AppEngine (for example client user authentication).